# How do i put online my Ckan platform?

Tags: ckan

I followed this tuto  http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html  , now i want to put my platform online , so other can access it online . Do i need to change ckan.site_url=[http://démo.clan.net](http://d%C3%A9mo.clan.net) ?

Answer (score 0):

To put your CKAN online, follow the 'deployment' docs: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/deployment.html

You're correct that you should update `ckan.site_url` - set it to your site's public address. However most things will work without it. It's used in the dataset Atom feed and Datapusher, for example.